# Dynamic SQL for updating any table !

Tags: sql

How to create a dynamic SQL statement, that will update any table given as one of parameter.   Here I believe, i couldn't use "Set Column1 = Value ....."  as the columns will differ according to the table.

Comment: This question has an exact duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531486/dynamic-sql-for-updating-any-table - I voted to close that one and keep this one, as it already had close votes.

Comment: Can you provide what database software you are using and what you are using at the application layer?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely poor idea.  You can create massive havoc with your database doing such a thing. I can't imagine any dba who would allow it. You need to know the specifics of a table to insert into it properly, you need to be aware of what fields are required and what fields have default values. You need to know what kind of information and data types should be in each field so that you do not send bad data to the database. One proc that does all cannot properly check these things and certainly can't ever be properly tested. Further it means permissions must be at the table level which is a poor choice for internal security as well as for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more context? Are you executing arbitrary SQL statements from within scripts, such as Perl, PHP, or Python? Are you just trying to get a command-line .sql script working? What database server are you working on?

The solution can vary widely depending on your situation.